# MySQL returns 'BLOB' data instead 'abcd' string

Tags: mysql, sql

[Return BLOB instead 'abcd'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBRsz.png)
When I'm studying SQL by MySQL Server. In 'Learning SQL' book, this query will return 'abcd'.Mine is 'BLOB' instead.

I tried to search Google but I didn't find my problem I need. How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO Huyen My!
[Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for any SQL query question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) Basically its useful to see a schema for the relevant table and some sample data.

Comment: It seems that your character set system variables are set incorrectly. Try to add `USING charset_name` to the function parameters.